# Getting error message as invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions while using this in karate.config

Tags: karate, ui-automation, headless, headless-browser

Below lines are used in karate.config file

```
karate.configure('driver', {type: 'chromedriver', executable: '#(driverpath)' , webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' , "goog:chromeOptions": { headless: true } } } } );
```

Error message

```
{"sessionId":"(#sessionid)","status":61,"value":{"message":"invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions\nfrom invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: headless
```

Comment: no idea. the error sounds pretty clear to me. maybe an old version of the driver, chrome etc. refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54035970/143475

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `addOptions` property of the driver config in Karate. But this may work only on driver type `chrome`.

Documented here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#configure-driver

This may work, but I haven't tried it:

```
addOptions: ['--headless']
```

Be aware that Chrome headless has had some changes recently: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

```
karate.configure('driver', {type: 'chromedriver', executable: '#(driverpath)' , webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' , "goog:chromeOptions": { "args": [ "headless=true" ] } } } } );
```

See the ***args*** option used here.